# Unable to import a python file (which uses multi-threading) into another python file

Tags: python, multithreading, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an issue while importing a python file (which contains a multi-threading class, that reads every row in the data base and a thread is started for every row.)

When I try to import this file from another python file, nothing is happening. As in, the kernel looks as if it hanged(blank). 
** Basically the code isn't progressing after the import line. It is getting struck there.
 Any suggestions or help?

**pseudo code** ( of the file I want to import)

```
import time
import MySQLdb   
import threading

class Job(threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self, x, conn, sleepBuffer=0):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)    
      self.x = x
      self.conn = conn
      self.sleepBuffer = sleepBuffer

      def run(self):    
        self.session = Session(hostname=self.x)
        self.job(self.x)

      def job(self, x):            
    ######### do something and update the database columns. It keeps running continuously and updates the table periodically. 

db  = MySQLdb.connect(####user,password,dbname)
cur = db.cursor()                
cur.execute("select x from TABLE where x = %s" %(x))
rows = cur.fetchall()
threads = []
for row in rows:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect((####user,password,dbname)

    time.sleep(1)
    thread = Job(row[0], conn)
    thread.start()

    threads.append(thread) 

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

I'm trying to import the file using the line "*import filename*". I thought may be I was doing it wrong and checked other ways of importing. But none of them work.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems in the one line of code you've shared. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @Kevin I edited the code. Its the complete code I would like to import. Any suggestions or help?

Comment: I'm not sure which chunk of code here is being imported. This isn't a case of "importing in python executes code not in the body of any function" misunderstanding, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this..

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```